# Split Row into separate cells by vbLf

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am nearly there with some code but need some help. Right now this code looks through the first row and then identifies any line breaks and puts them all into separate cells in Column A. What I want the code to do is drop the line break divisions underneath the respective column rather than all in column A. For example, if I had

```
A1: Red vbLf Blue vbLf Green
B1: 1 vbLf 2 vbLf 3 vbLf 4
```

I want this to surface as

```
A1: Red
A2: Blue
A3 Green

B1: 1
B2: 2
B3: 3
B4: 4
```

Here is the current code that I have. Keep in mind my row is A-Z.

```
Sub Split_test()

Dim cell_value As Variant
Dim counter As Integer

'Row counter
counter = 1

'Looping through A column define max value
For i = 1 To 26

    'Take cell one at the time
    cell_value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).value

    'Split cell contents
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    WrdArray() = Split(cell_value, vbLf)

    'Place values to the A column
    For Each Item In WrdArray
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(counter, 1).value = Item
    counter = counter + 1
    Next Item


Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is this code doing that is in error?

Comment: In my same example:
A1: Red vbLf Blue vbLf Green
B1: 1 vbLf 2 vbLf 3 vbLf 4

The code is surfacing as 
A1: Red
A2: Blue
A3: Green
A4: 1
A5: 2
A6: 3
A7: 4

Comment: This puts the export on `Sheet4` not in place of the values on the active sheet, Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `counter = 1` inside the first loop so it resets to 1 each loop.

And change the `Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(counter, 1)` to `Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(counter, i)` so it changes the output column.

```
Sub Split_test()

Dim cell_value As Variant
Dim counter As Integer




'Looping through A column define max value
For i = 1 To 26
    'Row counter
    counter = 1

    'Take cell one at the time
    cell_value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value

    'Split cell contents
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    WrdArray() = Split(cell_value, vbLf)


    'Place values to the A column
    For Each Item In WrdArray
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(counter, i).Value = Item
        counter = counter + 1
    Next Item
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting into a variant, and putting the transposed array elements back into the worksheet.

```
dim arr as variant, i as long

with worksheets(1)
    for i=1 to 26
        arr = split(.cells(1, i).value2, chr(10))
        .cells(1, i).resize(ubound(arr) + 1, 1) = _
            application.transpose(arr)
    next i
end with
```

Comment: This could use error control on a blank cell and possibly cells with no vbLF chars.